R: Automate exporting and designing multiple Excel documents pulling from different lists of dataframes
I posted a similar question from a different thread which helped tremendously.  Is it also possible to export and design multiple excel documents from a list of dataframes? For instance, I want the column headers bold and with column filters. Thanks!
Here is the code I have right now:
library(purrr)
library(writexl)
library(readxl)

df1 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "mpg")]
df2 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "hp")]
df3 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "disp")]

path <- tempdir()

list(
  df1, df2, df3
) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(paste("Spreadsheet", LETTERS[1:3])) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ split(.x, .x$cyl)) %>% 
  purrr::transpose() %>%  
  purrr::iwalk(~writexl::write_xlsx(.x, file.path(path, paste0("results_", .y, ".xlsx"))))


I'm not sure you can format column headers in bold and add column filters with {writexl}, but you can do it with {openxlsx}:
library(purrr)
library(openxlsx)

df1 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "mpg")]
df2 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "hp")]
df3 <- mtcars[c("cyl", "disp")]

list(
  df1, df2, df3
) %>% 
  purrr::set_names(paste("Spreadsheet", LETTERS[1:3])) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ split(.x, .x$cyl)) %>% 
  purrr::transpose() %>%
  purrr::iwalk(~ {
    wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
    
    purrr::iwalk(.x, ~ {
      openxlsx::addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = .y)

      openxlsx::writeDataTable(
        wb, 
        sheet = .y, 
        x = .x,
        tableStyle = "none", 
        headerStyle = openxlsx::createStyle(textDecoration = "bold")
      )
    })

    openxlsx::saveWorkbook(
      wb, 
      file = paste0("results_", .y, ".xlsx"), 
      overwrite = TRUE
    )
  })

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0
